# Display multiple 'childpaths' in a list AngularJs + Firebase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, angularfire

I'm new to Angular and Firebase and this is my first post. I'm making a TODO List which  can create many TODO topics,

for example, a TODO list for:

```
1.Work
2.Free Time 
3.Home etc.
```

The problem is that I can't display ALL the TODO list I've created only the most recent one appears. Every time a new Todo list is created I assigned them a path:

https://.firebaseio.com/todos/ + "newProyect"

This is my view the iterates through the TODO projects:

```
   <ul class="list-group" ng-init="projectListView()">
          <li ng-repeat="project in projects">{{project.title}}</li>
   </ul>
```

What I wanted to do here is make a function that can go through all the TODO list created the display them, but im only able to display the last one, each time the function looks for another path it erases the previous one. So you only end up displaying the last TOdo List. What can I do to fix this. Here is my code

```
    $scope.projectListView = function() {
           ref.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
              var project = snapshot.name();
              $scope.projects = [{title:project}];
          });
      };
```

Thank you in advance!!!
[i want to display something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4ayz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with firebase but one thing I would suggest is:
instead of this

```
$scope.projects = [{title:project}];
```

where you are overriding $scope.projects with a list containing only one project, add one more project to the list

```
$scope.projects.push({title:project});
```

Also, I would not do this in ng-init, but rather where the new project is created.